# I want to load this address in arcgisruntime100.14, but the map is not displayed after I load it，, please tell me where I am wrong

Tags: javafx, arcgis

I want to load this address in arcgisruntime100.14, but the map is not displayed after loading, but the coordinate system can be read, please tell me where I am wrong.Here is my code，Here is my code please teach me

I try to display the map, but according to the following code, only the coordinate system can be read, and the map cannot be displayed, how can I improve it？

```
map = new ArcGISMap();
String serviceUrl = "http://221.228.70.166:28080/OneMapServer/rest/services/jyyx2018/MapServer"; 
TianDiTuDownload.getToken10();
String token = TianDiTuDownload.strToken;
double xMin = 119.94217769801627; 
double yMin = 31.836474338353156; 
double xMax = 120.639868810773; 
double yMax = 32.066625556046766; 
Envelope initialExtent = new Envelope(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax,SpatialReference.create(4490));
map.setInitialViewpoint(new Viewpoint(initialExtent));
String securedServiceUrl = serviceUrl + "?token=" + token;
System.out.println( securedServiceUrl);
ArcGISTiledLayer   tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer  (securedServiceUrl); tiledLayer.addDoneLoadingListener(() -> {
                if (tiledLayer.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                            
                    tiledLayer.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    
                }
            });
tiledLayer.setVisible(true);            
map.getOperationalLayers().add(tiledLayer);         
mapView.setMap(map);

public static void getToken10() {
         String thishost = null;
         Map<String, Object> tokenBody = null;
         Map<String, String> requestHead = new HashMap<>();
         try {
             thishost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         String url = "http://221.228.70.166:28080/RemoteTokenServer";
         //String url = "http://58.211.227.180:8051/RemoteTokenServer";
         tokenBody = new HashMap<>();
         tokenBody.put("request", "getToken");
         tokenBody.put("username", "jyzgj");
         tokenBody.put("password", "Jyzgj@2023");
        

         try {
             URL obj = new URL(url);
             HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
             con.setRequestMethod("POST");
             con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
             con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             con.setDoOutput(true);

             try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                 wr.writeBytes(getRequestBodyString(tokenBody));
                 wr.flush();
             }

             int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

             if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                 try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                     String inputLine;
                     StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                         response.append(inputLine);
                     }

                     System.out.println("TOKEN="+response.toString());
                     strToken=response.toString();
                 }
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Failed to obtain token. Response code: " + responseCode);
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```